# Convert rows to columns in SQL Server table

Tags: t-sql

My table has the below sample data:

```
DECLARE @FHTable  table (PK_ID int,FK_ID int,P_ID int, T_ID int, A_day int,A_hour TIME,D_day int,D_hour time) 

INSERT INTO @FHtable VALUES (129,194,252,1005322,NULL,NULL,1,'02:30:00.0000000')
INSERT INTO @FHtable VALUES (130,194,311,1000891,3,'04:30:00.0000000',null,null)
INSERT INTO @FHtable VALUES (131,194,311,1000129,NULL,NULL,4,'03:30:00.0000000')
INSERT INTO @FHtable VALUES (132,194,252,1000025,6,'03:00:00.0000000',null,null)

SELECT * FROM @FHtable
```

My final result Should be of the below table:

```
DECLARE @FinalResultTable TABLE (FK_ID int,P_IDFrom int,P_IDTO INT, T_IDFrom int,T_IDTo INT, A_day int,A_hour TIME,D_day int,D_hour time)

INSERT INTO @FinalResultTable VALUES (194,252,311,1005322,1000891,3,'04:30:00.0000000',1,'02:30:00.0000000')
INSERT INTO @FinalResultTable VALUES (194,311,252,1000129,1000025,6,'03:00:00.0000000',4,'03:30:00.0000000')

select * from @FinalResultTable
```

The logic is there will be 4 rows for each FK_ID. The first and the second row is a source to destination and the 3rd and 4th row is again a source to destination.

Can you please help

Comment: Hey @SQL_yogi, welcome to the StackOverflow. what is the logic here..?

Comment: There will 4 rows for a FK_ID. the first row and the second row denotes a source to destination 252 is a source and 311 is a destination, so i want to convert the same into 2 columns like P_IDFrom and P_IDTo. same way the 3rd and 4th row denotes a source and destination as well.

Comment: @SQL_yogi but how you determine that destination? w52 is in 1st and 4th row, not 1st and second.

Comment: Please copy and paste your text into your question instead of posting screenshots of text. Right now your question says: "My table has this sample data: enter image description here I need a query to change the data to this: enter image description here", which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I don't understand what is the logical way to connect an arrival with a departure. You said "the first and the second", are you talking about the ordering by PK_ID ? So you assume that items are always ordered in the "good way"? this is not really safe.

Comment: yes ordering based on PK_ID. To be more clear for a FK_ID there are 2 legs. Leg-1 is row 1 and 2. Leg-2 is row 3 and 4

Answer (score 0):

As I pointed out in the comments, it's not very clear what is the logic that joins each arrival with the corresponding departure.

What it's clear to me it's that your title is wrong: you are **not** talking about converting rows to columns. Instead, you are just grouping 2 by 2 the rows of the table. So, you have 2 approaches, using a `GROUP BY` or just using a `JOIN`, it depends on what is exactly your logic.

Here is an example:

```
select A.FK_ID,
    A.PK_ID as P_IDFrom, B.PK_ID as P_IDTO,
    A.T_ID as T_IDFrom int, B.T_ID as T_IDTo,
    B.A_day, B.A_hour,
    A.D_day, A.D_hour
from @FHTable A
join @FHTable B on B.PK_ID+1=A.PK_ID
where A.A_day is null
```

(this assumes that an arrivals's PK is always +1 w.r.t. its departure).